# Why is the "Label Properties" window greyed out for editing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, layers, font

I'm running Win10 (32GB RAM, i5-7500) and QGIS 3.28.2-Firenze.
I have a project I was given to write a report on. In QGIS there are text labels not associated with layers (but describing them I believe). When I **toggle editing** and click the **change label properties** icon I can click on the text on the map.

The **Label Properties** window opens when I click on text, but all it allows me to do is change the text - but none of the properties of that text. All other options: >Display>Font>Buffer>Position are all greyed out and not accessible.

My goal is to change the font colour from black to white so it can be seen on the darker map. How do I make these options accessible for editing?

The **Help** button at the bottom of the **Label Properties** window is not helpful and brings me to the following link:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-label-toolbar

No sites seem to specifically address the **Label Properties** window in my searches.I'm sure it's something simple and apologize for bothering, but appreciate the help.

[image: Label Properties Window QGIS 3.28]

Answer (score 2):

To activate it, you have make some settings:

1. Go to the layers styling Dock (F7)
2. Click on the Data-definded overide box of the item which you want to change
3. Activate "Store Data in the Project"

[image]

4. A dialog appears and you have to select a primary key of your layer, which links to the auxiliary storage where the information will be stored
5. After that, the item - color for example - will be active in the label properties dialog

[image]

you can manage the fields and entries of the auxiliary storage in the layer property dialog:

[image]